# AWS Lambda C# Function , Issue with Return Success Always

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created one Lambda Project in C# , that is hosted on AWS . We have SQS from which this Lambda is getting triggered.

Due to running in parallel (only Insert) logic we are getting "Serializable isolation violation" error (XX000: 1023). We have checked that it is not possible to handle with the logic we have currently . So we want to rerun that message again if failed.

For the same purpose based on error I have "return true;" or "return false" from the code.

In case of return false , The Message from SQS is getting deleted , so we can no proceed with that.

The Return logic, I have added like below :

Project : AWS Lambda Function (C# Core 2.1)

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + " :: " + 
    Convert.ToString(ex.InnerException) + " :: " + Environment.NewLine + 
    ex.StackTrace);
    Console.WriteLine("Error :: Return Value 0");
    // To Handle SQL Rerun in case of Failure
    return false;
    //return ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace;
}
```

I am able to see the error in cloudwatch but it didn't stop "DLQ" to run because SQS is not failing (Deleted).

Hope to have solution for the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the integration to return the message to the queue you need to return/throw an error/exception. [Error Handling and Automatic Retries in AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-retries.html) talks about how you deal with errors in lambda and what the retry logic is like for different types of integrations.